# Unexpected Closed-Loop System Response of Longitudinal Aircraft Dynamics

Tags: control-engineering, matlab

I have a closed-loop system that represents the longitudinal dynamics of an aircraft with states x velocity, z velocity, pitch rate, pitch, and x and z inertial positions. The outputs of the system (where the system response is observed) are the pitch angle and z position. The realization of this particular system is completely reachable, and so I have placed closed-loop eigenvalues at -1.5, -2, -2.5, -3, -4, and -5. I have solved for the gain matrix that gives this desired behavior. In each modal space, the modal response is as desired; no oscillations and highly damped. However, when I simulate the system response to a random unit perturbation in the state space, the system response actually has oscillations. I figured that since all of the eigenvalues are strictly negative and real, that I should see no oscillation. Is the response I'm getting what's supposed to happen or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When a system is theoretically stable but diverges upon simulation, my first thought is that the numerical solver used by the sim is not adequate and what you are seeing is a spurious solution brought about by the discretization. Can you look into this and/or share more details about your model?

Comment: You eigenvalues look suspiciously close together.  Pole placement carries no guarantees of robustness -- you pretty much have to choose the pole placement by intuition, and then be ready to jigger them around, again by intuition.

Comment: Is your model a full nonlinear model?  If you're linearizing around an operating point, then designing a not-too-robust controller, then exciting the thing hard enough that the nonlinearities come in to play, the plant may be different enough from the model that things go unstable.  Or you're hitting numerical problems, as @AEheresupportsMonica suggests.  Please *edit your question* with more details on your model.